# How to import webcomponents.js correctly, so my polymer page works in both chrome and firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, polymer, polyfills

I've built a page that makes use of polymer and some custom elements. I was disappointed, that it only worked correctly in Chrome, which was a big setback. In Firefox and IE it only showed the page title and rest was blank, though no errors were reported in the console.
I googled allover the web, but could not find an answer that would resolve the issue (or maybe I just didn't understand it correctly..).

Today I found out, that when I import webcomponents.js like:

```
<script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
```

the page gets displayed in Firefox just as good as it did in Chrome. However, it doesn't show in Chrome anymore (blank page).

It seems to me, that Chrome will only accept import like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js">
```

Does anyone know a solution to this browser schizophrenia, i.e. how to import the script correctly, so both browsers will accept one code?

**EDIT**

Well honestly, I can't think of anything else that could be causing it but this line, because if you alter it, you either get nothing or everything displayed.

The page hangs at [premierleaguebar.php5.cz](http://premierleaguebar.php5.cz) and here is the code of `<plb-table>`, the custom element on the index page:

```
<dom-module id="plb-table">
<template>
    <link href="/public/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <style>
        table.data {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: 1px solid #41587c;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
        }

        table.data td, table.data th {
            padding: 6px;
            border: 1px solid #41587c;
            text-align: center; 
        }

        table.data th {
            background-color: #41587c;
            color: #ff0;
            border: 2px solid #666;
        }

        table.data tr:hover {
            background-color: #edf1f6;    
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-material/paper-material.html"/>
    <paper-material elevation="3">
        <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
        <table class="data">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="3">HRÁČ</th>
                    <th colspan="4"><abbr title="Played">ZÁPASY</abbr></th>
                    <th colspan="4"><abbr title="Played">HRY</abbr></th>
                    <th colspan="3"><abbr title="Played">SKÓRE</abbr></th>
                    <th colspan="2"><abbr title="Played">PRŮMĚRY</abbr></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>JMÉNO</th>
                    <th><abbr title="Počet odehraných zápasů">G</abbr></th>
                    <th><abbr title="Výhry">W</abbr></th>
                    <th><abbr title="Remízy">D</abbr></th>
                    <th><abbr title="Prohry">L</abbr></th>
                    <th><abbr title="Body"><b>P</b></abbr></th>
                    <th><abbr title="Legs Won - vyhrané hry">LW</abbr></th>
                    <th><abbr title="Legs Lost - prohrané hry">LL</abbr></th>
                    <th><abbr title="Legs Difference - rozdíl LW - LL">LD</abbr></th>
                    <th><abbr title="Nezavřené hry">N</abbr></th>
                    <th><abbr title="Načtené body (pro soupeře)">P+</abbr></th>
                    <th><abbr title="Obdržené body (od soupeře)">P-</abbr></th>
                    <th><abbr title="Points Difference - rozdíl P+ - P-">PD</abbr></th>
                    <th><abbr title="Marks Per Round - počet zásahů na kolo podle automatu co má dycky pravdu; Průměr ze všech her">MPR</abbr></th>
                    <th><abbr title="Průměrné kolo zavření při výhře">R</abbr></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{table}}">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{poradi(index)}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.nick}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.matchesplayed}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.win}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.draw}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.loss}}</td>
                    <td><b>{{item.points}}</b></td>
                    <td>{{item.legsfor}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.legsagainst}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.legdiff}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.unconcealed}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.nactenebody}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.obdrzenebody}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.bodydiff}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.mpr}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.zavrird}}</td>
                </tr>
            </template>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
    </paper-material>
</template>
</dom-module>

<script>
Polymer({
    is: "plb-table",
    properties: {
        table: {type: Array}
    },
    poradi: function (ind){
        return ++ind;
    }
});
</script>
```

**EDIT2**

I still think it's a Polymer and/or browser support issue. I bypassed it by checking the browser type ([get_browser](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)) and importing the webcomponents.js file according to the specific browser's likes. It's definitely not a webdesigner's "correct-solution", only my engineer's "just-get-it-working" style, but it does what I want it to do.

Anyways if any of you webdesigners would know how to address it properly, I'll be more than happy to hear it.

Comment: I think it is probably something else in your code. Show us some more

Comment: Hi, thanks for your effort. I've edited the post and added link to the page and code of custom element.

Comment: Check the browser console. There is an error

Comment: You don't need to load the webcomponents.js polyfill on chrome. Chrome supports web components natively.

Comment: @2pha Ok, I rewrote it, my console shows no errors now. It was a minor tho, only a mistake in parsing JSON array. The code still won't run in Firefox, so clearly the problem is hidden elsewhere..

Comment: @Snekw Thanks for pointing it out. I tested it and you're right. It doesn't help me with my problem though - I want the page to be visible in ANY browser, not just Chrome.

Comment: Why are all your imports scattered through the content? Try putting them all up in the head. Also, the webcomponents.js import is commented out.

Comment: @2pha I've tried importing everything in head before, no change. As I've read somewhere, importing an element right before its first use should improve performance (not that it would matter here..:) ).

Comment: Hmm, I have read a lot on Polymer 1.0 performance and have not read that. If you are looking for performance you should at least be using vulcanize via gulp or grunt. [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EUZWE8EZ0IU) is a video

Comment: Oh, And did you try un commenting the webcomponents.js ? I'm pretty sure that is your problem

Comment: @2pha I don't know if the scattered imports have any benefit either. As I said I just read it, so I've done it that way. Thanks for Vulcanize, I'll try that. But performance is not the issue here. I tried uncommenting the webcomponents.js import before, it had no effect.

Comment: it seems to be working in firefox for me now you have added the webcomponenets.js back in

Comment: @2pha It only is a workaround, see EDIT2. That's the point of my issue: use of `<link>` or `<script>`, each only works in one browser type.

Comment: you should be using script, and it should work in both. The fact that it doesn't makes me think that there is a different problem (because if this was really a problem with polymer, many more people would have reported it)

Comment: @matejhrachovina Your question incorrectly assumes that's it's valid to use `<link rel="import">` to import JS. That would cause this message on Chrome's console : `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/x-javascript`, and you'd find that no Web Components modules are defined (such as `HTMLImports`). The proper way to import the Web Components script is with the `<script>` tag (or by manually creating a `script` element in JS).